# how to change composer package autoload files

Tags: package, composer-php, autoload

in the project I am working on, we use composer to download/update a package which has defined autoload files section in composer.json.

These files are autoloaded in every script.

Is there a way, how could I remove those files, because I need them to be autoloaded only in a few scripts.

Thanks a lot.

Peter

Answer (score 0):

Create a pull request for that project that removes the need to include these files when bootstrapping the autoloading.

Apart from that, the answer is no.

You can however try to find a different library that does not include files. Or you can first try to find out how much of a performance impact that file loading really imposes on your application.